# CountIfs with Match OR Countifs with VBA variable location?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to do a countifs formula with 6 different criteria.

I was previously able to do a Vlookup with Match function, and I am trying to figure out if it is possible to do a similar formula with a CountIfs + Match.

This is the Vlookup + Match formula that is working perfectly (It is part of VBA Code)

```
=VLOOKUP(R[0]C4,'CRR Data'!C2:C300,MATCH(""" & CRRHeaderMatch & """,'CRR Data'!R1C3:R1C300,0)+1,0)
```

I am trying to do something similar with Countifs + match, but it does not seem to be working for me. Below is a simplified version with one criteria. I am trying to figure out if these 2 functions can even work together, or if I can somehow use VBA to find the header name and use that variable location within the formula.

```
=CountIfs(MATCH(""" & CRRHeaderMatch & """, B3)
```

Here is the full formula that I currently have

```
=COUNTIFS('Update IB Macro Result'!D:D,'Update IB Pivot'!C3,'Update IB Macro Result'!F:F, "Match",'Update IB Macro Result'!L:L,'Update IB Pivot'!A3,'Update IB Macro Result'!N:N, "Match", 'Update IB Macro Result'!O:O,'Update IB Pivot'!B3, 'Update IB Macro Result'!Q:Q, "Match", 'Update IB Macro Result'!K:K,"<>No Match", 'Update IB Macro Result'!N:N,"<>No Match",'Update IB Macro Result'!Q:Q,"<>No Match")
```

Issues with the current formula:

1. All columns from the 'Update IB Macro Result' tab may change and I have to figure out how to make them dynamic
2. The first 3 criteria can be blank, and the blank to blank counting is not working. I need to include these blank values, but when I tried by adding IF statement, it added all blank columns to 1.4 million

Can anyone help me resolve these 2 issues?

I cannot use a formula array as there can be hundreds of thousands of rows, and multiple criteria so it would take an extremely long time for that to process.

[Update IB Pivot Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MP8dF.png)

[Update IB Macro Result Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SZ535.png)

The formula on D2 of Update IB Pivot Tab:

```
=COUNTIFS(INDEX('Update IB Macro Result'!A:CA,0,MATCH("Service Level Name",'Update IB Macro Result'!$1:$1,0),1),C2,INDEX('Update IB Macro Result'!A:CA,0,MATCH("MSO#",'Update IB Macro Result'!$1:$1,0),1),A2,INDEX('Update IB Macro Result'!A:CA,0,MATCH("MPO#",'Update IB Macro Result'!$1:$1,0),1),B2)
```

Comment: to return the correct column to the formula you will need Index with the match: `INDEX('CRR Data'!C2:C300,0,MATCH(""" & CRRHeaderMatch & """,'CRR Data'!R1C3:R1C300,0)+1` this will return the whole column to the outer formula.

Comment: Ah okay I was able to figure out how to do that - Thank you! And then do you have any idea how to fix issue number 2?

Comment: the data can also be blank, or if the criteria is blank you want to include all the data in that column?

Comment: For the third formula above (full formula) , C3, A3 and B3 may be blank, and when any of those are blank, it is currently not counting the records as part of the count if. I am trying to get those records to count as well

Comment: again do you want to count where the data is blank or if it is blank it should consider all the data?

Comment: Yes if A3 is blank as an example, but all other criteria are met, I would like it to also count

Comment: then replace `'Update IB Pivot'!C3` with `if('Update IB Pivot'!C3="","*",'Update IB Pivot'!C3)` and do the same type of thing with the others.

Comment: For the above, both the SOURCE and FIND can be blank, so lets say that MPO# and MSO# are both blank at both source and find (Update IB Macro Result tab) but 'Service Level Name' has a value, if they match, then I still am trying to count it for that row

Comment: at this point we will need test data and expected output see how to create a [mcve].  otherwise we are just guessing.

Comment: Is there a way for me to upload excel file with the 2 tabs? not sure if that is against the rules

Comment: You can paste a link, but that is discouraged.  the question should stand on its own and a full workbook does not meet the `minimal` in [mcve]

Comment: I uploaded 2 photos of the tabs and the current formula, D2 should = 16, D3 should = 7, D4 should = 1